# Will 15.6 UHD screen with i5 intel 1250P on Ubuntu 20.04 be a good performer?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, laptop, scaling, hdpi

This is my first port on this platform. I am planning to buy a ubuntu laptop from dell with 15.6 FHD screen, 16 GB RAM powered by intel 12 gen i5 1250P cpu and 256+256 ssd storage accompanied by 58whr battery. I also have an option for UHD resolution display for approx $140 more. I cannot decide between FHD and UHD at this point due to technical problems I read online. My usage consists of :

1. Using Virtual machines (up to 3) via virtual box
2. Reading content on screen for long times
3. Java and python programming
4. MySQL workflow
5. Lots of browsing and web development
6. Dual boot with windows 10 for occasional windows specific things
7. I will hook it up with FHD displays at home

I have been reading that Ubuntu 20.04 is not good with scaling. As the OS is preinstalled I cannot upgrade on my own for few years. I cannot opt for a different configuration at this point.

Please help me decide the following

1. Will i5 12 gen handle the UHD screen performance without issues ? (Dell seems to say so)
2. Will I have lots of scaling issues if I use UHD display?
3. Will UHD display greatly enhance my reading and coding experience? Is it worth it?
4. Is FHD good for reading and other use cases I mentioned above ?

FYI

I am in my late thirties and wear glasses for cylindrical  and well as mild spherical correction. That is not say my eyes are aren’t 20/20.

Please advice. I want the best for my eyes that I can afford. I have been using Ubuntu 20.04 on my desktop for quite a long time now and I am quite satisfied.

Thanks

Comment: That new of a system needs 22.04 and then needs still newer kernels Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is planning to use the Linux 5.15 kernel as its default, if Alder Lake CPU you may want newer kernel
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu-2204-alderlake&num=1  I am  now retired & have to have glasses set for the computer screen distance.

Comment: @oldfred thanks fir the response. So the thing here is dell is installing and testing and selling the laptop to me. So I believe the compatibility with alderlake is probably fine. I main concern is uhd display or fhd other 20.04 and whether i5 is good enough for uhd.